# I came across this question of integer root and have no idea how to solve integer root

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> We call an element $x \in \mathbb R$ an integer root if there exist $k \in \mathbb N$, and $m \in \mathbb Z$, such that $x^k = m$.
>
> Use the definition to show, for $a,b \in \mathbb R$: if $a$ and $b$ are integer roots, then $ab$ is an integer root.

I started off by assuming $a^s = n$, and $b^t = m$, and couldn't work out the next step

Answer (score 2):

$(ab)^{st}=(a^{s})^{t}(b^{t})^{s}=n^{t} m^{s}$ which is an integer.